# Entering the first few letters of a “select” box on a web page on Android

Tags: android, html

I have a website with a 400-item HTML select list (drop-down menu). On Chrome for Windows and Internet Explorer, If I type the first few characters of an item it will jump directly to that item on the list. Is there any way to get the same behavior on an Android tablet? I've considered using a datalist instead, but that seems to come with it's own problems, so I'd prefer to get a select list working the way I want it instead.

I am able to chose what browser is used on the tablet, if this is something that can only be fixed client-side.

Answer (score 1):

"No". This widget is not getting IME attached so there's way user can type anything. And having 400 items select list asks from autocompletion (`<input>` + JS) - then you will be able to type.